# Error message in Android Studio when trying to run and load emulator for the first time

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

The error message is:

```
PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: C:\Users\Darth\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd\config.ini
```

I've looked in that directory and there is no config.ini file.  Only a userdata.img file.
When looking in the AVD manager the actions column says "Failed to load".  If I right click it and click details it shows an error of:

```
 Error: Failed to parse properties from C:\Users\Username\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21_x87.avd\config.ini
```

Fixes attempted that didn't work:

1 - Try choosing a different device definition. (config.ini file still missing when choosing multiple other devices)

2 - sharing the .android directory with my whole homegroup (selecting a device still doesn't generate a config.ini file, same error persists)

**FIX:** Thanks for all the replies.  The fix that worked was changing the Memory of the AVD to 512!

Comment: try to create a new emulator.

Comment: Tried.  Same issue.  No config.ini file.


Almost want to try to find the individual config file

Comment: @johnstamos having exactly same issue, tried everything people recommend, still the problem exists

Comment: Let me know if you find a solution.  I'm still looking.

Comment: This is definitely not the issue with the rights. Looks like to be the problem of the build, here is the same issue reported https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81552 I use Android Studio 1.0 RC 4, which one you are on?

Comment: Hey Volder.  It's been a month and a bit but found my fix with in editing the AVD's memory to 512 in the avd's advanced settings.

Answer (score 15):

I also had this same error, but the cause wasn't mis-matched x64 vs x86. Turns out my emulator failed to load because the skin wasn't defined. The way that I fixed it was:

1. Remove any previous wear emulators that failed
2. Pick the Model (Round/Square) and Android version(Lollipop, for instance)
3. On the final screen, click "Show Advanced Settings"
4. Scroll all the way to the bottom and set the "Custom skin definition" to "AndroidWearSquare" or "AndroidWearRound", which should be at the bottom of the skins list

Then after you're finished it should all just work!

Comment: AndroidWearSquare (and round) were missing from the list of skins for me. Browsing manually to the skin directory was the workaround.

Comment: I had no AndroidWearSquare and round skin either in the list or in the directory, but simply choosing "No Skin" solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

Just put the Android SDK in the same Drive where you have installed the Android Studio 1.0. There is a problem if these drive letters are different. This will definitely work for you.I have solved this last week.

Comment: Thanks @Avnish. It works. I was struggling with the problem from last 2 days. You make my day.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an AVD Manager from C:\User\<%USERNAME%>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78577#c25

Answer (score 1):

For windows:
1) in the environment variables add a new "system variables"
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows (select your home directory of android sdk )

2) modify system variables Path, add "%Android_SDK_HOME%\tools;"

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Now I am getting another error, but at least this passed that error :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created many emulators and never touch .android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21_x87.avd\config.ini
you just create an Emulator, try to avoid "warp user Data", chose the appropriate Device and target API, set the SD memory to amount you want, and do the same with external RAM,and there is no reason to not work.
guesses: may the \Nexus_5_API_21_x87.avd\config.ini is read only! or you don't have permission to access  .android/  (share this folder to all users,and give them full acsess.

I hope this will help

Comment: config.ini doesn't exist.  It's like it doesn't download.  I'll try creating my own.

Comment: ok focus on: you don't have permission to access .android/ (share this folder to all users,and give them full acsess.

Comment: Didn't work.  When I select the new emulator after clicking run, it still gives the same error.  As for the access... The file doesn't exist.  Even if it was a permissions issue the file it's looking for is not there.

Comment: you need a permissions  for a library : .android/ , ignore the file for now! if you dont' have full access (permissions) to .android/ the system cannot crreat the file.

Comment: Okay I've shared the .android directory with all of my homegroup.  Same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above I was facing the same issue.

For me it looks like the bug of the build and definitely not the issue rights, while another file was perfectly created (userdata.img) as well as the whole folder for the avd.

**Solution #1:** without changing anything in installation, I just found config.ini file in the internet. For example [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78577&q=config.ini&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) is the config.ini for Nexus_S_API_21

So then I created Nexus_S AVD and put the config file in the folder. Then it starts working.

The issue with this method:

- limited devices
- config updates manually through config file
- I still had some issues, e.g. instead of displaying the project I was displayed with the home page of Android, and there was no my app

**Solution #2:** Then I totally removed the Android Studio and cleaned all the stuff and downloaded 0.8.14 from scratch, during installation I updated it once to v.0.9.9. and then didn't update further.
In this version - everything worked just fine without any manipulation. AVD created from the first time and when launched - the project screen is displayed opened with Hello World.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to fix it with the below solution.

Root Cause: My system is 32-bit and the `config.ini` file was present in

```
C:\Users\Saajan Pruthi\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\Saajan Pruthi\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21.avd
```

Note the **x86**... I simply copied the config file into the later folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue inside Linux. The problem was that made install with root and executed the Android Studio from mi normal user, so in the momment that I install Android Studio every files android for emule stay here:

```
/root/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd

/root/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.ini
```

So you need do copy the files at your user, then:

```
sudo cp -Rf /root/.android /home/YOUR_USER
```

I hope that be help. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it worked:

1. moved the sdk folder from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk to the Android Studio program folder under C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\sdk
2. Restarted Android studio and reconfigured it to point to the new sdk folder
3. Recreated the emulator and started it

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I just removed the AVD and added it back again - emulator is running fine now.

Comment: How did you do this? `avd` in terminal says `command not found`, and I have no even idea whether it's the name of the executable, or there're some pre/post/infixes.

Comment: I did this through GUI if I recall correctly, I didn't do this since then so I don't remember

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out that my hard drive was full. For anyone still looking for a solution, definitely make sure you still have space.